# How to make insertAfter in parentNode

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a ul.li and I need to make a button that will take the specific li
with the button and move it one place down.
Because there is no "insertAfter" reference I can't find how I take
the next .li and make it up.

My code:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>amethyst
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button> 
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </li>
  <li>lavender
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button> 
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </li>
  <li>plums
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button> 
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS to the up button and the specific button

```
if(event.target.className == 'up') {
  let li = event.target.parentNode;
  var prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
  let ul = li.parentNode;   
  if (prevLi) {     
    ul.insertBefore(li, prevLi); 
  }

if(event.target.className == "down") {
  var lid = event.target.parentNode;
  var prevLiD = li.previousElementSibling;
  let ul = li.parentNode
  if (prevLiD) {
    ul.insertBefore(li, prevLi);
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Comment: You could just read up on how insertBefore works ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore: _“If referenceNode is null, the newNode is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes.”_

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

- To move `el` up (ensure that `el.previousElementSibling != null`):

  - `el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el.previousElementSibling)`
  - `el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.previousElementSibling, el.nextElementSibling)`
- To move `el` down, take the `el.nextElementSibling` and move it up (after ensuring it's not `null`):

  - `el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.nextElementSibling, el)`
  - `el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling)`